# Separate room for question management

Tags: discussion, migration, voting

SuperUser and ServerFault have dedicated rooms to manage "vote to close"

I propose one for dba.se too (note: I've already created it as "[Vote to Ellipsis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2476/vote-to-ellipsis)") to keep "The Heap" free. Posts about questions can get lost there in all the banter and chat

As well as closures, I'd suggest it'd be useful to manage migrations too
We can point the SO mods there, for example.

So, anyone against? And anyone have a better name?

### Update

We're already talking bollocks in this room and posting Qs in "the heap".

Fail.

Comment: Maybe a SQL appropriate name would be `Vote to @Action`

Comment: `$action` from MERGE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say just keep the VTC room as a link farm of the questions so they don't get lost in the volume of bollocks (which is only going to increase).  Even if the discussion takes place in The Heap the links can be stashed in the VTC room, and it is useful in that capacity, even just as a personal link farm for people doing community mod work.

Comment: Sorry about the fake edit to change my vote - I think this is a good idea but before it's time :-)

Comment: Also I just discovered how much having 2 rooms makes my head spin :-)

Comment: It wasn't a rip-roaring success, but it was definitely easier to keep track of questions when they were posted in the VTC site.  The amount of bollocks on the main site (OK mea culpa) pushes them off the top pretty quickly if you want to refer back to them.

Comment: would starring them help?

Comment: For some reason I can't get the system to let me star my own chat postings.  Don't know whether this is by design or not.

Comment: only incidentally. Also, these Q should not be just for closing, but for mentoring. Let's not focus so much on closing questions, as guiding the askers to better questions.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells it's by design. If you were a room owner, you could pin them, then unpin them, and the system would leave it starred by you (a bit of a bug/workaround, but it exists nonetheless. pinning by default stars it, unpinning does not unstar)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be the obligatory negative voice. I don't think there's so much banter in [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) that we won't be able to deal with actual migrations or other issues, and it's likely to get missed pretty often, with people coming to the Heap looking to resolve issues, so you'll have two rooms for that.

Granted, you'll have a room of those who are most likely to know the site's goals, and be best able to help with migrations, but in six months, I doubt this room will have remained unfrozen.

However, it's not my community, but ours, so we have two things to do here:

- If everyone else wants the room, then by all means let's use it,
- **If there are outstanding issues, they should be raised on meta, always**.

  - <sub>some people don't understand that concept ;-) - as opposed to GBN who does</sub>

Comment: fair call. Shall we agree to "suck it and see"?

Comment: I'd say let's try it (meaning have the room).

Comment: OK, you win. Failing already... COTW has an idea though